# How to prevent a cmd execution from printing text back to the screen in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

In PowerShell I'm doing a cmd call to execute a program.

```
$create = "CreateFile /username Test /password password123"
cmd.exe /c $cred
```

When this program is executed via command line it prints to the screen "Command ended successfully." and this text seems to be returned from the cmd to my PowerShell script and tries to execute the line. So I get the error:

```
cmd.exe : Command ended successfully
At E:\Install\Files Script.ps1:12 char:17
+ $returnString = cmd.exe /c $cred
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Command ended successfully:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

My understanding is that the line

```
cmd.exe : Command ended successfully
```

Is trying to be executed by my PowerShell script and therefore it's throwing an error. Is there a way for me to prevent my command line call to the program to prevent from printing to the window? I've tried calling

```
echo off
```

prior to executing and I get the same result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use Windows command processor `cmd.exe` to run an executable (`CreateFile.exe`?)? An executable can be run directly by PowerShell without usage of `cmd.exe`. See for example [call operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html). Or is `CreateFile` a batch file? Yes! Why not replacing the command lines in batch file by appropriate command lines in PowerShell script. PowerShell is much more powerful than CMD and so everything coded in a batch file can be coded also in a PowerShell script. The usage of two script interpreters for one task does not really make sense.

Comment: @Mofi I apologize as I'm rather new to PowerShell and it's full potential has been a lot for me to chew on so far. Your comment makes a lot of sense and I now see the error of my approach. My task was to write a PowerShell script to automate the execution of (3) batch files in their proper order, but as you noted it makes way more sense to just replace the batch files with a single PowerShell script with the contents of each inside.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I was able to find a solution that seems to work in my case. I've added:

```
/f >nul 2>&1
```

To my script, and it seems to have solved my problem. My new script:

```
$create = "CreateFile /username Test /password password123"
cmd.exe /c $cred
```